# Get my HTML to activate the JS, and be able to select information from my array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have made an array with 3 names, and i basically want it so, if someone types in one of the names in the array, i want it to show an alert box, well basically showing that the JS is doing something.

Cheers Guys.

```js
var names = ['Alex', 'Dale', 'Mike'];

var nameSelector = document.getElementById('name-area').value;

function nameGrabber() {
  if (nameSelector === names[0]) {
    alert("Nice Name bro.");
  } else if (nameSelector === names[1]) {
    alert("Mate, that's a name that you have.");
  } else if (nameSelector === names[3]) {
    alert("Ok that's fine.");
  } else {
    alert("PUT IN ONE OF THE NAMES PLEAZE... thanks :)");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Javascript Lesson</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name-area"></input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="nameGrabber()"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the nameSelector variable into your submit function, otherwise the value of nameSelector always remains the initial value of the input field (which is empty). Something like:

```js
var names = ['Alex', 'Dale', 'Mike'];



function nameGrabber() {

var nameSelector = document.getElementById('name-area').value;

  if (nameSelector === names[0]) {
    alert("Nice Name bro.");
  } else if (nameSelector === names[1]) {
    alert("Mate, that's a name that you have.");
  } else if (nameSelector === names[3]) {
    alert("Ok that's fine.");
  } else {
    alert("PUT IN ONE OF THE NAMES PLEAZE... thanks :)");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Javascript Lesson</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="name-area"></input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="nameGrabber()"></input>
</body>

</html>
```